# Laravel: what is the 'password' in $request->password?

Tags: php, laravel

This question related to article [Laravel 5.4: Login with Username or Email](https://sujipthapa.co/blog/laravel-54-login-with-username-or-password). There, it was suggested the next method of custom authentication:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request){
    $field = filter_var($request->get($this->username()), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
        ? $this->username()
        : 'username';

    return [
        $field => $request->get($this->username()),
        'password' => $request->password,
    ];
}
```

What means '->password' in `$request->password`? Field's `name` attribute? What if my password field's `name` is `passoword1`, for example?

```
<input type="password" name="password1" required>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 5.4 you can get input from the $request using

`$request->input('password')`

for input like

`<input type='text' name='password'>`

For your example with name="password1" you would use `$request->input('password1')`.

Here are some helpful documentation links :)

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/Request.html

Answer (score 1):

It is called dynamic input properties. Whatever parameters exist in the request can be accessed from Laravel Request instance `Illuminate\Http\Request`. In this case the input parameters exist on this object as props. They are dynamic props so you get the point. The Request instance has all sorts of method to deal with all kind of things.

A couple ways to get input data, like

```
<input type="text" name="a">
<input type="text" name="b">



public function methodName(Request $request){
   $a = $request->a;
   $a = $request->b;

   // Or
   $input_params = $request->all(); // input parameters array ['a' => 'some value', 'b' => 'some other value']

   // Or
   $input_a = $request->input('a');

   // check if input exists
   if($request->has('a')){
       //****
   }

}
```

There are very nice examples and clear details here [Illuminate\Http\Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests)